# Odoo v9 Issue with columns not sorting on related fields

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

I have an issue where columns are not sortable on certain related fields.

I have extended the res.partner form with the following code snippet:

```
class CrmProject(models.Model):

_name = 'crm.project'
_inherit = ['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin']
_inherits = {
    'res.partner': 'partner_id',
}
_order = "name asc"


@api.model
def _get_domain_employee(self):
    ids = self.env.ref('aim_contacts.res_partner_business_2').ids
    return [('business_id', '=', ids)]
    .
    .
industry_id = fields.Many2one('crm.project.industry', 'Construction Type')
```

I have extended the sales/opportunity module with the following snippet:

```
class CrmOpportunity(models.Model):
_name = 'crm.opportunity'
_inherit = ['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin', 'aim.res.common']
_order = 'name asc'

@api.model
def _get_domain_employee(self):
    ids = self.env.ref('aim_contacts.res_partner_business_2').ids
    return [('business_id', '=', ids)]

name = fields.Char('Topic', required=True)
    .
    .
crm_project_id = fields.Many2one('crm.project', 'Project', track_visibility='onchange')
industry_id = fields.Many2one('crm.project.industry', 'Construction Type',related='crm_project_id.industry_id', readonly=True)
```

The view is defined as follows:

```
<record id="crm_opportunity_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">crm.opportunity.tree.view</field>
  <field name="model">crm.opportunity</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <tree string="Opportunities">
      <field name="name" string="Topic" invisible="1"/>
      <field name="crm_project_id"/>
      <field name="industry_id"/>
    </tree>
  </field>
</record>
```

Issue 1:
When the opportunities page is loaded, clicking on the "Construction Type" (industry_id) header does nothing.

Issue 2:
Also, when clicking on the "Project" (crm_project_id) header, the column is sorted by id rather than name (even though it is displaying name).

I thought issue 2 could be resolved by adding to crm.project.py:

```
_order = "name asc"
```

but it did not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

The method of adding store=True to related fields works. There is an issue though that if the field is already created, then it will/may not update with the most resent data.

To get around this, I created another field with the same information as the original, and then linked to it. I have read that others drop the fields and create them again.

Comment: Did my answer help you @3piece?

Comment: Yep, it was your answer that was correct and helped. The stale-cache issue in odoo needs to be worked around. At-least I know this for the future of designing related fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Related fields are not stored in the database, and you can't order by a field which is not stored in the database, so the solution to that part is to add a `store=True` to the related field:

```
industry_id = fields.Many2one('crm.project.industry', 'Construction Type',related='crm_project_id.industry_id', readonly=True, store=True)
```

Your *Project* field should be working OK, have you checked in the tree view of `crm.project` if the records are ordered by name? Check also the `name_get` method of `crm.project` and its `display_name` field. You can solve this problem adding other stored related field to your `crm.opportunity` model:

```
crm_project_name = fields.Char('crm.project', 'Construction Type',related='crm_project_id.name', store=True)
```

And in your XML:

```
<record id="crm_opportunity_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">crm.opportunity.tree.view</field>
  <field name="model">crm.opportunity</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <tree string="Opportunities">
      <field name="name" string="Topic" invisible="1"/>
      <field name="crm_project_id" invisible="1"/>
      <field name="crm_project_name"/>
      <field name="industry_id"/>
    </tree>
  </field>
</record>
```

Do this if you're in a hurry (while you're looking for the problem). But I'll do the related field to `name` and also the related field to `display_name`, and order them in the tree view to check what happens (if `display_name` column is ordered by ID, then the problem is the `name_get` method or the `display_name` field, no doubt).

Comment: Thanks @forvas for the detailed answer. Strangely when I add store=True to the industry_id field, it allows me to sort the column, but there is no data. i.e. all the previous data is missing in the entire column. When I remove the attribute, the data returns.

Comment: I've tried this approach on 2 other columns and it works. However, for some strange reason, on industry_id, no data is present. When store=True is not set, then there are over 7,000 records. but when it is set, there are 0.

Comment: @3piece that's may be because only the new records (created from now on) are going to be stored in the database. Try to create a new record and check if its `industry_id` is stored in the database. If so, that's the reason.